# Android Studio, Github login problem incorrect credentials

Tags: android-studio, github

I've started working with Android Studio and I found a problem when trying to connect to Github. I've tried restarting Android Studio and even creating a new project, but I am not able to login.

I installed Git and it´s working in the local repository.

The problems are:

Incorrect credentials
Request response: 401 unauthorized

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't log in to GitHub on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869735/cant-log-in-to-github-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Project from Version Control, it has git.

What I did was I logged in through a token, it also tells you what needs to be added to the token and that worked for me.

You can create the token here:
https://github.com/settings/tokens

Answer (score 6):

Note: I found this solution on: [Can't log in to GitHub on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869735/cant-log-in-to-github-on-android-studio).
Such solution worked perfect for me!

On GitHub:

- Log in -> Click on your avatar in the top right hand corner
- Choose Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens
- Click on the "Generate new token" button
- Add a note if you want (in my case was mandatory), like "Android Studio"
- Select repo(all), read:org (under admin:org), gist
- Click on the "Generate token" button
- Copy the token

On Android Studio:

- Go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub
- Add an account (plus button on the right side, choose "log in with token")
- Click the "Use Token" hyperlink, like in your screenshot
- Paste your token, click login, click ok

Comment: this works for me, should be tested if you have some similar issue

Answer (score 5):

I got the issue solved by generating a token from https://github.com/settings/tokens and using it to add account option on Android Studio>File>settings>GitHub

Answer (score 1):

you can install git in your operation system and use command for add your android project to github repository.

1- you should install git bash

2- open git bash in your project directory and initial it as a git repository

- git init -b main

3- add your project to the local repository

- git add .

4- commit your file to the local git repository

- git commit -m "First commit"

5- Create a branch, usually called a 'main' or 'master'

- git branch -M main

6- define remote git url

- git remote add origin remote repository URL

7- finally, you should push all your project into remote git repository

- git push -u origin main

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues can be there to block you from accessing your github repo and throwing 403 error. Hence please go step by step.

Step-1 : Local git is corrupted or not working

`git branch -r` [If it gives result you are good]

```
git ls-remote --heads  <remot_git_location>
```

if one of the above is working then your local git is good. If not use

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Step-2 : From your IDE (IntelliJ or Android Studio etc) see git is configured and test it.

Go to Default Settings-->GitHub and Your host should be "https://github.com"

Get your Github personal token. Login to your github account from browser. Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens.
o   Select all “repo”, gist and “read.org” in your scope.
o   Create the token

Last step: If still not working, Go to VCS--> GIT --> Remotes --> Change the repo to include token explicitly

```
https://user_name:<your_TOKEN>@github.com/reponame.git
```

Paste the token in your IDE and test the connection.
If your problem still persists then check if there is network issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to AndroidStudio 4.1.1 allowed me to access with my credentials without having to generate a token.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all required settings (see image [GitHub settings required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqdN0.jpg)) at your GitHub account at https://github.com/settings/tokens/, and then you have to update the token (You must regenerate your token if you havent copied yet).... Then you can insert your credentials again in Android Studio and... ¡ready!