# Can't log in to GitHub on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, authentication, github

I can't sign in to GitHub on Android studio, as the picture shows.

[image]

I have reset my password, tried to put ' https:// ' in the server box, and still doesn't let me in and shows the same message.

I can no longer update the project I am working on with my team.
For some reason I was still able to commit and push to the repo and the changes were visible online.

Answer (score 225):

Try this:

On GitHub:

- Log in -> Click on your avatar in the top right hand corner
- Choose Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens
- Click on the "Generate new token" button
- Add a note if you want, like "Android Studio"
- Select repo(all), read:org (under admin:org), gist, workflow
- Click on the "Generate token" button
- Copy the token

On Android Studio:

- Go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub -> Add an account
- Click on the "Use Token" hyperlink, like in your screenshot
- Paste your token, click login, click ok

[image: "Log in to GitHub" prompt]

Comment: When I re-generated token which is made before, it doesn't works, But GENERATE NEW TOKEN save me!! Thank u

Comment: Latest Android studio version, click use token and then generate

Comment: For macOS on Android Studio:

Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Version Control -> GitHub -> Add an account

Comment: File->Settings->Version Control menu items don't exist for me on MacOS, Android Studio Arctic Fox. So I did as mentioned above in GitHub, then back in Android Studio, I told it to "push" again and that brought up a prompt to use either Username/password or Token. I selected Token, then pasted in the token.

Comment: I cant push share the project it show permission denied, any solution for this

Answer (score 24):

1. Go to the https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Click Personal Access Token from the left menu.
3. Select repo and gist
4. Generate your token
5. Paste the token to your Android Studio

Edit** in step 3, you must select (repo, gist, and **read:org**)

Comment: Thanks for the read:org edit. That was what I had been leaving out.

Comment: Thank a lot. You save me a day.

Comment: For those having followed the advice above and still having issues - try invalidating caches and restarting.

Answer (score 16):

For me, after doing the token sign up using the Android studio UI in `Preferences - Github` also requested again username/password after doing git pull, what I did to solve it is to place my username and in password paste again the copied token

[image]

Steps

- Go to github developer settings
- Generate a new token with repo, gist, read:org privileges
- Copy the token
- Go to android studio `preferences-github` press the `-` sign if you have another account and press the `+` sign to add a new account
- Go to the use token link
- Paste your copied token
- Now your account is added to the IDE, press `apply` and `OK`
- Now do a git pull (if you already are in a repo)
- If asking for username , place your github username
- If asking for password, do not put your github password, instead paste again the token you created there and press enter

Comment: I solved it simpler way doing your step by clicking `Android Studio` -> `Preferences` -> `Version Control` -> `Github` & you will prompted to login due to the failed. (NOTE: I am using android studio 4.0.1 might work for > 4.0)

Answer (score 9):

Check if you have [activated 2FA](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/configuring-two-factor-authentication) on your account.

If you have (two-factor authentication), then the password you should enter would actually be a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token), in [your settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens), not your GitHub account password.

Comment: With activated 2FA only way was to generate token. I was wondering why I couldn't log in normally with my credentials.

Comment: Have to be an accepted answer because it contains an explanation what is wrong with the credentials login.

Answer (score 5):

### Android Studio Arctic Fox Solution (Windows 10)

I was authenticated in Android Studio Arctic Fox (Latest Version) using a personal access token, but still, I was getting this error on August 14, 2021:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

I generated a new access token on github.com, removed my GitHub account from Android Studio, and added the account again with the new access token. But still, it was showing the same error.

Reading other solutions on SO, I downloaded the GitHub CLI, and added my GitHub account in the windows command prompt with the access token successfully, and tried to push the repo from Android Studio again, which again failed.

Then following [this article](https://jimmy-shen.medium.com/august-13-github-requested-url-403-5a03a34721f0), I did the following in command line:

```
cd <project-directory>
git remote set-url origin https://<TOKEN>@github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git
```

Pushed again from Android Studio. It worked finally!

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Android studio, click `Use token` and then `Generate`. Your browser will open the link and then click on `Generate Token`, copy the code and paste it on `Android studio`.

Answer (score 1):

Login with password deprecated, please use below method

In Mac
Change Token --> Android Studio -->  preferences --> Version Control  --> GitHub --> Change Token

In GitHub Account
GitHub Generate Token --> Settings --> Developer Settings --> Personal Access Token

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Version Control > Git > Mark the "Use credential Helper" box and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

For me login didn't work had to remove existing github profile in android studio and add again with renewed token