# Why do I always get the error message "Server is unreachable" when I try to connect to my Github account in Android studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I tried to change the url of github but i can't. I already tried to connect via Tokens but that doesn't work either. I receive the same error when using token login.

[image: Error Message, for picture click here]

[Error after push, click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Ad7.png)

Comment: are you using 2F auth in you github account? If you use it, you need to create personal access tokens instead of username/password

Comment: No I don't use 2F auth.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920231/12438238 and let me know if this works for you

Comment: now after pushing, i get the error in the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

What host are you typing? You should just use github.com instead of the whole url or whatever.

Also maybe you should prefer to use a token instead, Github -> Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens, create one and use that to login.

Also check if you are using http on your repo and you are sending the credentials to the same url but with https. then you should change your repo to https too.

Hope that one of those 3 solutions will work

Comment: I use github.com. Token connection doesn't work either. I get the same error message.

Comment: Can you provide an image with the error popping up ?

Comment: I use https for my repo.

Comment: you can use token login instead ,try it see if it works

Comment: Yeah token is actually straight forward, seems weird it doesnt work. Maybe you can provide with a screenshot? ^^

Comment: If I try to push it, after token login, i get an "empty server reply" back.

Comment: Restart your local server. If that doesnt work restart your PC. If that doesnt work run :

git fetch origin --prune

Comment: Restarting your computer will do the work 99%

Comment: restarting didnt help