# How to add a GitHub account in Android Studio Artic Fox

Tags: android-studio, authentication, github, account, android-studio-arctic-fox

After updating to latest IDE.

> Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1

I wanted to sync my project which has been updated, with the one on my GitHub account.

I tried connecting to my account based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920231/11214643

But the behavior has changed, now the link :
[image: Add Account]
redirects me to an IntelliJ web-page without any token alternative.

[image]

After selecting the "Authorize in GitHub" option, a second window with a pop-up appears.

Nor the Google, the IntelliJ or the GitHub accounts are valid on the textbox, nothing works.

[image]

Do I need to fix some local environment variable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Go with this Steps

### 1). click on Project from Version Control

[image]

### 2). Click on "Github" from Lefy Panel and go with "Use token..."

[image]

### 3). Then you get your Screen to login with Token

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @nikunj-paradva, btw your UI looks amazing!

Comment: i am using this [theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui)